# OSX: Right-Click without selecting current word

Tags: macos, context-menu, selection, right-click

Whenever I make a Right-Click (I use Trackpad) the word underneath gets selected and I see menu items related to selection, such as Copy, Lookup, etc.

This looks to be universal in all OSX apps, at least seen in Chrome and iTerm2.

Is it possible NOT not select the word underneath the pointer when I do Right-Click? The idea is that without selection the menu is different, and selection masks out proper context menu.

Comment: When you hover your mouse pointer over a word, the contextual menu that comes up with right-Click (or CTRL-Click) is pertinent to that word:  Lookup, Search, etc.  If you hover your mouse over white space on the page (mouse cursor is an arrow instead of insertion bar), then the contextual menu will be appropriate for the *page* rather than a word.

Comment: Thanks! Generally agreed. However, the problem is that sometimes the item I need right-click on consist of words only, and it's difficult (takes some effort) to find a spot outside of any word.